# How to prove that an ordered set is a lattice.

Tags: lattice-orders

I am given an interval $a,b$ with $a \le x$ and $x \le b$ . How can I prove that this let s call it $( L ,\le)$ is  a lattice ? I know it is probably stupidly simple but I would appreciate some help .

Comment: Use the definition. Take any 2-element subset of $(L,\le)$ and prove that it has both infimum and supremum in $(L,\le)$.

Comment: You must have some more information. It is not true that every interval in a poset is a lattice. Which elements belong to $L$, and how are they related by $\leq$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### According to @amrsa, your question is incomplete. I've answered this by assuming $(L,\le)$ is a chain.

Use the definition. Let $A=\{x_1,x_2\}\subseteq L$. Then you need to show two things.

1. $A$ has an infimum in $L$
2. $A$ has a supremum in $L$

---

For infimum, you need to show that $\exists i \in L$ such that

- $i \le x_1$ and $i \le x_2$
- $\forall x\in L$ if $x \le x_1$ and $x \le x_2$, then $x\le i$

For supremum, show that $\exists s \in L$ such that

- $x_1\le s$ and $x_2\le s$
- $\forall x\in L$ if $x_1\le x$ and $x_2\le x$, then $s\le x$

---

### Hint:

Choose $i=\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $s=\max(x_1,x_2)$ and show that they satisfied the above criteria.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the ordered set is a chain. That was not stated.

Comment: @amrsa Isn't an interval a chain?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, in any lattice $L$, if $a<b$ then $\{x\in L:a\leq x\leq b\}$ is an interval, often denoted as $[a,b]$. An example is take any finite lattice $K$, with maximum $1$ and minimum $0$, and then we have $K=[0,1]$. Since not every finite lattice is a chain, then not every interval is a chain.

Comment: @amrsa I see your point now. I'll state the assumption in my answer until OP's clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your help , and indeed , the ordered set is a chain , I apologize for not stating that from the beginning .